# Laravel - rename key associative array with the 'as' keyword?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, associative-array

Is there a way to easily rename a key in an associative array without extra complexity?

for example

```
public function rules()
 {
   return [
    'candidateID' => 'required|number', **as candidate_id**
    'note'        => 'required|string',
   ];
 }
```

Comment: What is your database column name and what you want to rename and why ?

Comment: the column name is 'candidate_id'
im getting the data from the server as candidateID, and I would like to save any renaming down the road by doing so at the request incoming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This `exists:table_name,candidate_id'`

```
public function rules()
 {
   return [
    'candidateID' => 'required|number|exists:table_name,candidate_id',
    'note'        => 'required|string',
   ];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cab use Customer message for validation where you can return any message you want.

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
                'candidateID.required' => 'candidate_id required.',
                'candidateID.number' => 'candidate_id  must be number.',
        ];
    }
```